# Github Actions: Run workflow only on latest tag?

Tags: github-actions

```yaml
on:
  push:
    tags:
      - '*'
```

This would run the workflow on all the new tags pushed. Is there a way to only run the workflow on the latest tag among the new tags which are pushed?

Comment: You could get the latest tag name in your steps using the commands described here: https://gist.github.com/rponte/fdc0724dd984088606b0 (setting them into a variable if needed).

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - 'refs/tags/*'
```

Or this:

```
on:
  push:
    tags:
      - *
```